# Guidance to setup the local server for existing ROR app on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ROR and I'm trying to run the existing rails app on local server. But somehow it fails when I'm trying to migrate the db. See the full trace below

> rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- eventmachine C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`block in require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thin-1.7.2/lib/thin.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in`require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`each'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in`each'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler.rb:114:in`require'
>   C:/promotracks-rails/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>   C:/promotracks-rails/Rakefile:4:in`'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in`load_rakefile'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in`block in load_rakefile'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in`load_rakefile'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in`standard_exception_handling'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in`'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/rake:23:in `load'
>   C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/rake:23:in`'

(I have ruby, rails, gem and bundler installed)

Comment: Have you got eventmachine in your Gemfile?

Comment: No, I don't see it in my gemfile

Comment: add `gem "eventmachine"` to your Gemfile and run bundle install.

Comment: Did that but now when i try to rake db:migrate it throws this error LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.4/rubyeventmachine
C:/promotracks-rails/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/promotracks-rails/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Can you try running it as `gem install eventmachine --platform ruby`

Comment: it gives same error

Answer (score 0):

Gist of it Rails app are not compatible with windows environment so just switch to mac or linux.

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs shared in the post:

Although eventmachine is provided as x64-mingw platform gem, it doesn't support ruby-2.4 or 2.5 earlier which is fixed now . So would recommend you to do the following:

Firstly, (on Windows + Ruby 2.4) to make sure you remove all versions of eventmachine e.g.

```
gem uninstall eventmachine
```

Then reinstall using the below mentioned command:

```
gem install eventmachine --platform ruby
```